# Fetching Url of a website through shell scripting

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, wget

I am trying to build a shell script which on execution can fetch the url of a website into a text file, so that i can use that text file as an input to wget

Comment: If you're really trying, then show the script you have so far.

Comment: Fetch it from where ?

Comment: What do you mean by _fetch the url of a website into a text file_.  Where would it be fetching from?

Comment: fetch url from a website running on my browser. Basically I do not want to manually write the url repeatedly, so i thought I can assign this task to a script which when executed will automatically fetch the url from the website running on my browser(lets say only 1 tab) and wget will treat that text file as its input.

Comment: I do not think browsers have an API for "getting the URL in a tab" I think you'd rather need to create a browser addon/extension for that. Maybe, depending on your browser, there might also be a way to extract the url from the browsers history, which should exist as some file on disk.

Comment: http://whatHaveYouTried.com. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple solution for Firefox:

Firefox updates the [places.sqlite](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Places.sqlite) database everytime you visit an old or new url, i.e., every time one of the location bars of one of your tabs changes.

It is quite easy to query this database via SQL. Here is a little script that watches the file and prints any changes to the console:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
places=$(find $HOME/.mozilla -name places.sqlite)

lastDate=0

warn(){
    echo "$*" > /dev/stderr
}

fail() {
    warn "$*"; exit 1
}

[ -f "$places" ] || fail "places.sqlite not found"

warn "starting to watch $places at time: $lastDate"

while sleep 1; do
    count=$(sqlite3 $places "select count(*) from moz_places where last_visit_date > '$lastDate'")
    if [ $count -gt 0 ]; then
        sqlite3 $places "select url from moz_places where last_visit_date > '$lastDate'"
        lastDate=$(echo "$(date +%s%N) / 1000" | bc)
    fi
done
```

You can redirect the output to a file if you like: `sh watchscript.sh > myfile.txt`

Comment: Thanx Juve,I installed sqlite, found that places.sqlite file, but when I saw its contents using SQLite manager there wasn't any data.Infact I found browsing history in a table named moz_inputhistory in a database named "main".
I tried this:
sqlite test.db
sqlite version 2.8.17
Enter sqlite --help for help
sqlite>.tables
It showed nothing, not even a single table.

Comment: I think you need to `apt-get install sqlite3`. `sqlite` did not work for me.

Comment: I did this:-
 sqlite3 places.sqlite "select * from moz_inputhistory">foo.txt,it says permission denied,do we need to import the tables first??

Comment: No, I do not think so. For me it just worked. Try this: `db=\`find $HOME/.mozilla -name places.sqlite\`; wc -l "$db"; sqlite3 $db "select count(*) from moz_places"` -- On my system this yields: `11435 /home/juve/.mozilla/firefox/.../places.sqlite`
`12332` -- This shows that my DB is not empty and obviously also has some tables.

Comment: dont know how but today I tried it worked,.tables command is now showing all the tables.Thanx juve.

Comment: I am sharing my shell script,
location of my shell script--->/home/akshayaj/Shell Scripts/firefoxx.sh
location of places.sqlite----->/home/akshayaj/.mozilla/firefox/x3epy44.default/places.sqlite
my shell script so far..

clear

sqlite3 .mozilla/firefox/x3epy44.default/places.sqlite "select url from moz_places"

but it is giving an error "unable to open database"..please tell me where am I wrong

Comment: I am not sure. Here are some hints
1. You should avoid using spaces in dir/file names. A dirname like `Shell Scripts` is likely to cause problems.
2. Run any command from the command line first (without a script file) and carefully think how to make this command a reusable script later. Make sure it works first.
3. Copy&Paste the command text into a new file and execute `sh yourfile.sh` in the same dir as you had executed the command before.
If this does not work, I am really not sure what additional bugs you may have. Good Luck!